# Editar PDF con ITextSharp C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo un documento ya hecho (la plantilla por así decirlo), ese documento contiene una tabla a la que le tengo que agregar una fila y cambiar la fecha que está escrita en el documento. Una vez editado ese documento, debo "copiarlo", cambiarle el nombre y guárdalo en otra ruta.

Cómo puedo editar un archivo `PDF` existente con la librería `ITextSharp`,  una vez editado, ¿Cómo puedo guardar los cambios en un nuevo documento?

Comment: Has intentado algo? Que es lo que quieres editar?

Comment: Hola, es un poco complejo lo que quiero hacer. Tengo un documento ya hecho (la plantilla por así decirlo), ese documento contiene una tabla a la que le tengo que agregar una fila y cambiar la fecha que está escrita en el documento. Una vez editado ese documento, debo "copiarlo", cambiarle el nombre y guárdalo en otra ruta. Taambien estaba pensando si se puede hacer eso con un documento word, y una vez hecho todo lo anterior, convertirlo a PDF. Muchas gracias

Comment: No es complicado por lo que describes es solo generar una tabla, que seria lo dinámico, me imagino que la demás estructura se puede quedar fija a nivel de código, no le veo mayor problema, pero deberías de compartir lo que haz intentado para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Hola, mira, lo que quiero hacer es editar un texto del  pdf con el diseño ya hecho, en pocas palabras hacer o que hace el Metodo Replace(string oldValue,string newValue), pero en el pdf, y una vez editado, hacer un nuevo pdf con el editado